# How to give permissions to create only User role to manager in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, spree

Currently i have two roles, the defaults, 'User' and 'Admin'.

And i added a new role called 'Manager' with the permissions to manage Order, User

```
class ManagerAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize user
    if user.has_spree_role?(:manager)
      can :manage, Spree::Order
      can :manage, Spree::User
    end
  end
end
```

If the Manager is logged in he can able to manage Orders and Users, Her he can able to create new User with Admin role. But I need an ability to create only 'User' not 'Admin' or other 'Manager' roles.

Using spree_auth_devise - 2-2-stable

I appreciate if any one can help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not somthing that is currently supported by Spree out of the box.

You're going to have to modify Spree's [UsersController](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.2.2/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/users_controller.rb) in order to add this restriction.  It currently doesn't support any restrictions on roles.  You will need to modify (at a minimum) the create and update functions to put a check to see if the logged in user is allowed to create/update a user to the newly selected role.